# Renew math operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

There is an already defined math operator inside TeX that I want to change it by another letter. I am just wondering what is the best practice. Below I give an example for the `\Pr -> "Pr"` command to transform `\Pr -> "P"`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}    
\renewcommand*{\Pr}{\operatorname{P}} % is this the correct form? 
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{P} % any renew equivalent to this definition?
%\def\Pr{\qopname\relax m{P}} % like it is defined inside 'amsopn' package

\begin{document}

    $\Pr (\gamma \leq \Gamma_{min}) = F_\gamma (\Gamma_{min})$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg you are probably right. But the code there is to much :). I am just wondering if my approach (especially with the \renewcommand, will give me the same spaces as with the original \Pr

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer `\let\Pr\relax\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{P}`

Comment: Any special reason for that? Nevertheless, I will your approach. Thanks

Comment: With `\DeclareMathOperator` the defined command is robust.